# How to find parent div a selection range belong to

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is in following format

```
<div id="viewer">
   <div id="pageContainer1">
       lot of other divs are inside this 
  </div>
   <div id="pageContainer2">
       lot of other divs are inside this 
  </div>
   <div id="pageContainer2">
       lot of other divs are inside this 
  </div>
 </div>
```

What i want is whenever a text selection happens on the page i want to fetch the "pageContiner" div it is in .

Comment: provide fiddle for it to get more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/BQSJ3/140/)**

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#viewer div *').mouseup(function (e){
      alert($(this).closest('[id^="pageContainer"]').attr('id'));
    })
});
```

Comment: Whoever -1'ed this one: Why? This is *exactly* what the question is about.

Comment: what if text selection range in emebedded at the nth level inside "pageContainer*" div and n is not fixed ?

Comment: @rajesh:what do you mean by that??

Comment: @ Milind I dont know under what div this text selection will happen .

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar yes i have checked it and updated html code . so when you click on "something else" text i want to fecth "pageContiner" div id

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48357/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-rajesh)